# Using various Avro's schemas to consume one topic and one schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I've some confuse with Kafka's consumer.  Can I use various schemas to consume one topic with the schema registry?

**Publish:**

Full Schema:

```
{
    Name: "",
    Sex: "",
    Phone: "",
    Address: ""
}
```

**Consume:**

Schema A:

```
{
    Name: "", 
    Phone:""
}
```

Schema B:

```
{
    Name: "",
    Sex:"", 
    Address:""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same schema on both sides. Using your example, the deserializer using Schema A wouldn't know it needs to skip some bytes that represent sex to get to the bytes that represent phone.

The implementation of the deserializer can deserialize to an object that doesn't have a sex field by just ignoring that data but it has to know the byte array contains it which is what the schema provides.

Answer (score 0):

When using Avro, you have a writer and reader schema. When the reader only defines a subset of fields, those are matched by name and are the only ones deserialized

Comment: cuz I have more applications to consume data and each application needs authority control does it can realization?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: It means someone should use Schema A to consume data and others should use Schema B to consume data

Comment: So, can I publish Full Schema to the topic then use Schema A or Schema B to consume data?

Comment: Neither thing that you posted is an actual avro schema, but assuming they were, then you could publish any one of them and consume with any one of them, depending on if you've provided default values for any mismatched fields in the consumer